# R AOV Error() model is singular

Tags: r, anova

I am trying to run an ANOVA on a 5x5 design, where each subject only saw 5 of the 25 possible conditions. So subject A saw,

```
1,1; 2,2; 3,3; 4,4; 5,5
```

and subject B saw

```
1,2; 2,3; 3;4, 4;5, 5,1 etc.
```

Is it incorrect to use a within subject ANOVA since its not a true within subjects design?

This is what I was using,

```
(aov(Risk ~ Moral * Age + Error(ID/(Moral * Age)), data = Home)
```

and I get

```
Warning in aov(Risk ~ Moral * Age + Error(ID/(Moral * Age)), data = Home) :
  Error() model is singular
```

Here is a sample of the data

```
          ID   Age  Moral Risk
1         90   two affair    2
2         90 eight    vol    2    
3         90   ten  invol    2    
4         90  four   work    3   
5         90   six    gym    4    
6        117   two affair    9    
7        117 eight    vol    2    
8        117   ten  invol    3   
9        117  four   work    9  
10       117   six    gym   10  
11        70   two affair    3 
12        70 eight    vol    3 
13        70   ten  invol    2
14        70  four   work    6
15        70   six    gym    6
16        51   two affair    4
17        51 eight    vol    3
18        51   ten  invol    3
19        51  four   work    4
20        51   six    gym    6
```

Comment: how many subjects total?

Comment: @Ashley: Not responding in a timely fashion to a sensible question is considered impolite. You should be monitoring your SO questions for a couple of hours.

Comment: Sorry there are about 150

Comment: I thought I had email alerts on, and so I figured no one responded, sorry again!